# x-auth-token not passed in header when making a request

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

```
headers = {'x-auth-token': token,'Content-type':'application/json'}  
url2="http://192.168.56.1:8081/whitelist"
print "HEaders",headers
re=requests.get(url2,headers=headers)
print re.content
r = requests.post(url2, data=json.dumps(file_as_inp))
print r
print "code:"+ str(r.status_code)
print "******************"
print "headers:"+ str(r.headers)
print "******************"
print "content:"+ str(r.content)
```

I am writing a script so as to post data to a webservice. I am passing auth-token and content type in header and a list of json values as payload.
The file_as_inp contains list of json values as

```
[{'ip': '10.1.2.3'}, {'ip': '10.3.4.5'}, {'ip': '10.8.9.A'}, {'ip': '0'}, {'ip':'00'}, {'ip': 'null'}, {'ip': '10.9.4.5'}, {'ip': '10.7.6.2'}]
```

Headers contains :

```
{'Content-type': 'application/json', 'x-auth-token': u'313e95e7-ce08-46bf-8891-6d68fc615170'}
```

I am running my service on one command prompt and on other command prompt I am running this script. I get response as 200. When I print r.headers i get some output as

```
headers:{'Content-Length': '57', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Max-Age': '21600', 'Server': 'Werkzeug/0.11.9 Python/2.7', 'Date': 'Fri, 13 May 2016 04:47:52 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'HEAD, GET, POST, OPTIONS', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'}
```

However, when I print `r.content`, I get the below line printed :

```
content:x-auth-token not passed in header, please pass the token.
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong? Why am I getting the above line as output? After I post data to the webservice, I need to perform validations and check if IP is valid or no. But, I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting the header values when you are calling the POST request. You can change you code to:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(file_as_inp), headers=headers)
```

Or the recommended way would be to use the [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) object.

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. Sessions can also be used to provide default data to the request methods. This is done by providing data to the properties on a Session object:

The `x-auth-token` will be added onto the header of every request you make using the `Session` object. Your code should then look something like this:

```
sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers.update({'x-auth-token': token,'Content-type':'application/json'}  )
url = "http://192.168.56.1:8081/whitelist"

resp = sess.get(url, headers=headers)
print resp.content

resp = sess.post(url, data=json.dumps(file_as_inp))
print resp.content
```

Comment: Thanks . I already added header. I am even getting my script output as desired. However whenever I run my script the second type, the output gets appended to last output. y is it so ?

Comment: @IramKhan - I'm not sure why exactly that is happening. You should post another question for it.

Comment: I fixed it  by below code:    r = requests.post(url2, data=json.dumps(file_as_inp),headers=headers)
      print r
      # re=requests.get(url2,headers=headers)

      print "code:"+ str(r.status_code)
      print "******************"
      print "headers:"+ str(r.headers)
      print "******************"
      print "content:"+ str(r.text)

Comment: @IramKhan - That is the same solution which I suggested. What is the difference?

Comment: Thanks JRod :) . When I run my script for the second time, I get previous response body data too along with the new one in r.content. Can u suggest me a fix ?

Comment: When i call r.content. Previous output gets appended with new one. Can someone please help.

Comment: @IramKhan - I think the issue is with the REST service you've created. Check the code for that.